# How to set tkinter Entry Border Radius

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my first question to here. I don't know how to set Border Radius for Tkinter Entry, Thanks for your Help!

Comment: You may use tkinter.Text instead of Entry to configure height and width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to set a border radius on the tkinter or ttk `Entry` widgets, or any of the other widgets in those modules. Tkinter doesn't support the concept of a border radius.

Comment: damn that's sad